# Reverse an array in C Programming

Tags: c, arrays, reverse

I'm stuck on a piece of code I have been working on. I need to receive N number of inputs using argc and argv[] parameters. Then the N number of inputs will allow the user to enter that many sentences. For every sentence, my code should reverse every word in the sentence. Currently, my code will take in the N value and sentence, but won't print the reverse sentence. Instead, it prints a blank line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define SIZE 80

void get_input(char *line){
 fgets(line, SIZE, stdin);
 char *ptr = strchr(line, '\n');
 if (ptr){
     *ptr = '0'; }
}

 void reverse(char *line){
 char copy[SIZE];
 char word[SIZE];
 memset(copy, 0, SIZE);
 int line_len = strlen(line);
 int word_len = 0;
 int i;
 for(i=line_len; i<=0; --i){
     if(line[i] == ' ' && word_len > 0){
        memset(word, 0, SIZE);
        strncpy(word, line + i + 1, word_len);
        strcat(copy, word);
        strcat(copy, " ");
        word_len = 0;
     }else if(isalnum(line[i]) || line[i] == '\'')
          {word_len++;}
  }
  if(word_len>0){
     memset(word, 0, SIZE);
     strncpy(word, line, word_len);
     strcat(copy, word);}
     strcpy(line, copy);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
 int N = (int)strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
 if(N<0){
         printf("ERROR: Please provide an integer greater than or equal to 0\n");
         return 0;
        }
 if(N>SIZE){ printf("ERROR: Please provide an integer less than or equal to 80\n");
             return 0;
           }
     char line[SIZE];
     int i;
     for(i=0;i<N;i++){
                      get_input(line);
                      reverse(line);
                      printf("%s\n", line);
                     }
 return 0;
}
```

Example Input:

> 1
>
> The fox jumped over a log

Example desired output:

> log a over jumped fox The

Current output:

> 

Comment: "my code does everything correctly but does not print the reverse sentence. Instead, it prints a blank line. " - since that's the only thing it was supposed to do, surely it *doesn't* do everything correctly?

Comment: Made the edit in my post

Answer (score 2):

You put `<=` instead of `>=`

```
for(i = line_len; i <= 0; --i) {
```

Comment: What does `*=<` mean?

Comment: x >= z: this means X is higher than or equal than z.
x <= z: this means z is higher than or equal than x.

Comment: Okay but `*=<` isn't an operator.

Comment: My mistake, I meant <=.

Answer (score 0):

A simple silly mistake:

```
for(i=line_len; i<=0; --i){
```

What does this loop do? Well, first it sets `i` to `line_len`. Then it loops *while `i` is less than or equal to zero*, and at the end of each loop it decreases `i` by one.

This will loop for a long time (until `i` overflows) if `line_len` is zero, and otherwise it won't loop at all (because `i` will be greater than 0).

You probably meant `>=` instead of `<=`.

You also might've meant `i=line_len-1` instead of `i=line_len`, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: Yup, that is what I have been missing this whole time thanks

Answer (score 0):

EDITS: Changed the i<=0 in the for loop to i>=0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define SIZE 80

void get_input(char *line){
 fgets(line, SIZE, stdin);
 char *ptr = strchr(line, '\n');
 if (ptr){
     *ptr = ' '; }
}

void reverse(char *line){
 char copy[SIZE];
 char word[SIZE];
 memset(copy, 0, SIZE);
 int line_len = strlen(line);
 int word_len = 0;
 int i;
 for(i=line_len; i>=0; --i){
     if(line[i] == ' ' && word_len > 0){
        memset(word, 0, SIZE);
        strncpy(word, line + i + 1, word_len);
        strcat(copy, word);
        strcat(copy, " ");
        word_len = 0;
     }else if(isalnum(line[i]) || line[i] == '\'')
          {word_len++;}
 }
  if(word_len>0){
     memset(word, 0, SIZE);
     strncpy(word, line, word_len);
     strcat(copy, word);}
     strcpy(line, copy);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
 int N = (int)strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
 if(N<0){
         printf("ERROR: Please provide an integer greater than or equal to 0\n");
         return 0;
        }
 if(N>SIZE){ printf("ERROR: Please provide an integer less than or equal to 80\n");
             return 0;
           }
     char line[SIZE];
     int i;
     for(i=0;i<N;i++){
                      get_input(line);
                      reverse(line);
                      printf("%s\n", line);
                     }
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very good attempt at the reversal. However, you may be making it a bit more difficult than it need be. If you are simply reversing the order of the arguments, you can either print them out in reverse, or if you want to build a string out of the reversed arguments, simply concatenate them in reverse order with `strcat`. There are a lot of ways to do it, but a fairly straight forward approach is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 1024

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char string[MAXC] = "";
    int i, len = 0;

    for (i = argc - 1; i && len + strlen (argv[i]) + 2 < MAXC; i--) {
        strcat (string, argv[i]);
        strcat (string, " ");
        len = strlen (string);
    }
    printf ("%s\n", string);

    return 0;
}
```

Which simply starts with the last argument index `argc - 1` and then so long as the argument index is greater than `0` (`i`) and you are within your allowed number of characters `len + strlen (argv[i]) + 2 < MAXC` (`+2` to allow for the *nul-terminator* and the `' '`), concatenate the argument to your string `strcat (string, argv[i]);` and add a space `strcat (string, " ");`

(you can add `if (i > 1)` before `strcat (string, " ");` to eliminate the trailing *space*).

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/str_revargs The fox jumped over a log
log a over jumped fox The
```